# iPhone: Nib files not working correctly when copied with *.m & *.h files from 1 project to another

Tags: iphone, nib, xib

I've been building projects in pieces, prototyping different aspects of the whole in separate demo projects. I'm now in the process of migrating class and nib files from the prototypes into the target project and when I do so the nib files aren't behaving as they did in the prototype. I've been doing the migration by using the "Add Existing Files" item in the menu available in the hierarchical project file view.

Has anyone experienced behavior like this, and if you have do you have any suggestions for fixing the problem? In a number of cases I've simply recreated the nib file in the target and that has worked, but I'm trying to migrate a fairly complicated nib file with 3 different views. I'd prefer not to recreate it by hand if I can avoid it.

I'm using Xcode 3.1.4 on Leopard with iPhone SDK 3.1.2.

Comment: Are you moving .nib or .xib files?

Comment: More detail would be useful. What isn't behaving as expected? What errors do you get?

Answer (score 1):

When you migrate files in the manner you described. The hookups in IB aren't necessarily done for you automatically. You then have to go into IB and make sure all of the outlets are set, and the classes have the ownership you intend.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but the hookups were all made. What I didn't state clearly was that the Nib file was created for Landscape mode, and in the original app the coordinates were landscape relative. In the migrated app the coordinates the coordinates are appearing portrait relative, even though the Nib is still configured for Landscape. 

Something is causing the Nib's coordinate settings to be interpreted incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the main NIB file in your project `Info.plist` file.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but the Nib I was migrating wasn't the main Nib. The main Nib is working fine, and is set in the Info.plist file.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem. I did following, may be helpful for you ::
1. Add the nib file to your new project along with your .h and .m file.
2. Break all the connection and remake all the connection and do save.
4. Also break connection with file owner and re make it.
5. And then make all connections again.
This worked for me